# How do I make a hex literal a decimal literal in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra, decompiler

There are a few places where the decompiler displays a number as a hex literal when it's much clearer as a decimal literal. How do I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the number

Convert -> Unsigned Decimal:

[image]

Comment: This works in the disassembler output window ("Listing") but there's no "Convert" entry for numbers in the decompiler output window ("Decompile").

Comment: so true, I missed the "Decompile" word distinction in the question

Comment: interesting also change a number to a const/enum using Equate in the Listing window, it is not respected in the disassembly window. Sounds like a bug report should be opened.

Comment: Just checked and there's one already open: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/21

Comment: This fixes the decompiler output nonetheless.